# How to understand JSON syntax errors?

Tags: json, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a mock JSON server for a single page app I'm creating but I haven't used JSON so it's very much learn by doing. When I try to start the server I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Malformed JSON in file: ./json_server/data.json
Trailing comma in object at 15:5
```

Can someone explain what the `in object at 15:5` means?

I understand the error (other than the 15:5)and imagine I could easily find and fix it. However, I'm assuming the `15:5` is an indication of where in my code the error is, similar to syntax errors displaying the line number but I can't understand it. So I would  like to understand it to aid faster fixing of such problems.

Comment: 15:5 means line 15, column 5

Comment: Please add your code so we can have a look.